# Why isn't Listview displaying values from DataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a ListView & a DataTable (with Columns and Rows) that I have set as the Listview's DataSource & binded it, but my ListView will not display the data. ANy help? Thanks very much in advance

In thing.aspx :

```
 <asp:ListView ID="lvInstructors" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ShowRegularGridWhenEmpty="False"
    EmptyDataText="No Sessions to Display."
    OnRowDataBound="lvDataBound"
    OnRowCommand="lvCommand"
    Visible="true">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <div class="container" id="mainContent">
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="row instructorItem">
                <div class="col-2 sessionStartTimeDiv">
                    <p class="sessionStartTime"><%=SessionStartTime %></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 instructorHeadshotDiv">
                    <asp:Image class="instructorHeadshot" runat="server" src="" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-5 sessionInfoDiv">
                    <h3 class="instructorName"><%=InstructorName%></h3>
                    <p class="sessionInfo"><%=SessionInfo%></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 checkInBtnDiv">
                    <asp:Button class="checkInBtn" OnClick="CheckInBtn_Click"
                        ID="checkInBtn" runat="server" Text="CHECK-IN" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <br /><br />No Sessions to Display
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

In thing.aspx.cs :

```
       //Make Data table to hold ListViewItem Data 
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("SessionStartTime");
        dt.Columns.Add("InstructorHeadshot");
        dt.Columns.Add("InstructorName");
        dt.Columns.Add("SessionInfo");


        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["SessionStartTime"] = "1:00:";
        //dr["InstructorImage"] = "Bob";
        dr["InstructorName"] = "Bob";
        dr["SessionInfo"] = "Computer Room 2";

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        //Bind datatable to lv
        lvInstructors.DataSource = dt;
        lvInstructors.DataBind();
```

SideQuestion: (Not sure I need one here, but) When should I use a ListViewItem ?

Comment: How much of your data is actually displaying. If you had to put a rough percentage on it?

Comment: @PerpetualJ just edited with a photo - meant to include originally, thanks. But to answer your question the answer is 0 - none of it is showing up :(

Comment: How many rows does `dt` contain when you assign it as `DataSource`? It looks as though the answer should be `1` and I'd like to just confirm that.

Comment: @PerpetualJ Yup, you're right. Rows.Count = 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to bind - `#` - and `Eval`.

```
<%# Eval("SessionStartTime") %>
```

Use this format for the other values/columns.

Comment: oh man @wazz Thanks so much man that works perfectly.

Can you explain (or point me in the direction of a resource) the difference between <%=SessionStartTime %> & <%# Eval("SessionStartTime") %> , because the former didn't return any errors so it must do something, right?

Comment: I think the main thing was the missing Eval. ASP.NET sees and knows what to do with Eval(), and the fact that it was missing meant that what you had on the page amounted to plain old text. [Here's one old link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178366(v=vs.140)) i saved that might help a bit. [Also...](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dancre/2007/02/13/the-difference-between-and-in-asp-net/).

Comment: I appreciate the help & responses so much. Thank You !